# Bash Script for showing difference between two text files

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, scripting, diff

Lets say I have two lists:

`guests-2016.txt`:

```
Peter
Michael
Frank
Dirk
```

`guests-2017.txt`:

```
Mark
Michael
Dirk
Lilly
```

How may I create two new lists of guests

1. Guests that were in `guests-2016.txt` but are not in `guests-2017.txt` (`former_guests.txt`)
2. Guests that were not in `guests-2016.txt` but are in `guests-2017.txt` now (`new_guests.txt`)

Blank lines should be ignored. Only standard utilities should be used.

My idea would be to use `diff` and do some post processing.

Comment: Check out the manual page for `comm`.  Then add what you have tried, and explain how it did not work as you intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given two *sorted* files, `comm` would do this for you.

See the combinations of the `-2 -3` and `-1 -3` command line options, for example.

Comment: Thanks I did not know comm before. How to skip blank lines?

Comment: @NoobieNoob There are no blank lines in you example data, nor will there be any in the output from `comm`.

Answer (score 1):

Check, does it do the job. I can add an explanation, if you are needed.

```
awk '
/^$/{next}
FNR == NR {guest_2016[$1] = 1}
FNR != NR {
    if(!guest_2016[$1])
        print $1 > "new_guests.txt" 
    delete guest_2016[$1];
}
END {
    for(i in guest_2016)
        print i > "former_guests.txt"
}' guests-2016.txt guests-2017.txt
```